# Isabelle warning explanation

Tags: isabelle-hol

I'm dipping my toe back in the water with Isabelle after a 4-year hiatus, and once again finding it a bit frustrating. Here's a sample theory file based on an early chapter of [this text](https://bookdown.org/aleksander_mendoza_drosik/learn-isabelle/fundamentals-of-isabelle.html#inductive-data-types):

```
theory Drosik1
  imports Main
begin

hide_type nat (* get rid of the natural number type defined in Main *)
datatype nat = Zero | Suc nat
primrec plus :: "nat ⇒ nat ⇒ nat" where
"plus Zero y = y" |
"plus (Suc x) y = Suc (plus x y)"

theorem add_associativity: "plus x (plus y z) = plus (plus x y) z"
proof -
   show ?thesis 
     by auto
qed
```

I don't think that there's anything surprising there. I've used by own proof rather than the authors, and it seems to work OK, but I get a warning of some kind:

[image: Confusing warning from Isabelle]

A ctrl-click on the red exclamation at the left of the "by auto" line yields a tooltip saying "Marker", but somehow I suspect that's not really the point. Clicking and moving around, I can't find anything that says what's wrong, and the theorem ends up proved..so... what's up here?

BTW, replacing `by auto` with `try0` gets me "No proof found", and the same goes for `try`. It's rare that I can find a proof that `try` cannot, so I'm definitely baffled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, `auto` cannot prove the claim.

However, if you do induction on `x`, then `auto` can figure things out; this would be done as follows:

```
theorem add_associativity: "plus x (plus y z) = plus (plus x y) z"
proof (induction x)
  case Zero
  then show ?case by auto
next
  case (Suc x)
  then show ?case by auto
qed
```

You can make it more succinct by combining everything into one step. This can be too terse sometimes, like eating a steak in one bite. But if you want, it'd look like this:

```
theorem add_associativity: "plus x (plus y z) = plus (plus x y) z"
  by (induction x) auto
```

This tells Isabelle to do induction on `x` and apply `auto` on the resulting goals.

Comment: Thanks for that answer. But if you actually try this, then click after the qed, you'll see that it's a theorem, so apparently somehow it *did* get proved. I certainly agree that an induction tactic will work, but my question is about *what happened* (and what the interface is telling me), not "what's the best way to do this."

Comment: @John Ah, I see what you mean. That is because Isabelle is trying to parallelize proving things, so it doesn't want to block later proofs with getting hung up on this one invalid proof. It should not halt other proof-checking threads. It **does not** mean that the proof `by auto` was accepted. Such is my understanding of Isabelle, at least.

Comment: OL ... but surely that unproved result should not be treated as a theorem, and yet  `thm "add_associativity"` reports it is one. Nope...you're right. When I click near the `by` in the problematic line, down in the "Output" window, where I need to scroll down to see it, there's a "Failed to apply initial proof method" highlighted error. (In my case the nice "No subgoals!" report was the last thing I could see without scrolling, which mis-led me). The fact that this non-theorem is reported as a theorem without any 'sorry'-like thing seems...troubling, but surely there's a reason. Thanks again!